# VB code to convert text file to UTF16

Tags: .net, vb.net, unicode, utf-16

I am new to VB Code and struggling with Encode, Decode stuff. I need help with converting a text file from ANSI to UTF-16LE in VB.NET. This is what I have done so far. Later I am using BulkInsert for database operations and end up getting garbage data like

> ∩┐╜000000000000000000000094409574896680&∩┐╜

which is supposed to be

> Ì095837491150000349192784421039109162%Î

FYI, the database columns are NVARCHAR.

```
Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(filePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(pPath & pFilename & "_TEMP", True, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
    While Not sr.EndOfStream
                sw.writeLine(sr.readLine)
    End While
sr.Close()
sw.Close()
```

Could anyone help, please? Thanks.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: I am ending up with data like **┐╜000000000000000000000094409574896680&∩┐╜** whereas I need something like **Ì095837491150000349192784421039109162%Î** .. I dont know what I am doing wrong. I could only find BULK INSERT doesnt do well with ANSI file .. so thats why I am trying to convert file into UTF16 format.

Comment: How can you tell what you are ending up with?  What are you viewing the results with and how are you comparing it with what you need?

Comment: Just `∩┐╜` is enough to tell that there is at least CP437 and UTF-8 involved and the numbers changing cannot be because of character encoding conversions alone for sure. Show *all* relevant code.

Comment: Well its not only code which is a mere part of the program, but also the process that I am struggling with. The process in a nutshell :
 - Read from txt file
 - Convert to UTF16
 - Insert to Database (Bulk Insert)
 - Create Crystal Report

After the insertion I am checking in the database and thats where I am checking the data.

Comment: @Sanjay yes, and looking at the result it certainly looks like encodings got mixed up at every possible interaction point. If you don't post code, then nobody can help you.

Comment: You have to isolate each step and check the input and output of each step along the way to see when and where it goes wrong.  The debugger is your friend :)

Comment: I am just wondering - why would anyone want to convert a file to UTF16?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ReadAllText` and `WriteAllText` methods:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(dest, File.ReadAllText(source, Encoding.Default), Encoding.Unicode)
```